# Luroth's theorem for Discrete valuation rings?

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, fields, valuation-theory

Luroth's theorem states that if $k$ is  a field and $L$ is a field extension of $k$ such that $k \subset L \subseteq k(X)$, then $L=k(f(X))$ for some $f(X) \in k(X) $ . My question is ; is there any analogous result if we replace field $k$ by a PID or a local PID i.e. DVR  ?

Comment: What is the analogue of $k(X)$?

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly: fraction field of $R[X]$, where $R$ is a DVR say, and $L$ is some ring extension of $R$ ...